# Flutter objects taking up the entire screen width and don't know why

Tags: flutter

In my flutter project my elements unexpectedly taking up the entire screen width and I don't know why. For example buttons width is equal to screen width. I added the screenshot of app.
Here is the code for home page:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TrainingSettings(),
              Timer(),
              MyButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is code of my button:

```
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyButton({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.pause),
          Text("Pause"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried into new project and this time i have no issue my button works as it has to be.

[image]

Comment: show code of MyButton()

Comment: create column inside row and put button inside column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change mainAxisSize to MainAxizSize.min

```dart
 Row(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.pause),
          Text("Pause"),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) It solved my problem. But I was curious. When I do the same structure in a different project, it shouldn't need "mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min". Why do I need it now?

Comment: Well, without seeing the other project, it's hard to tell: my best guess is that in the widget tree some parent had already its horizontal size constrained. Mind that the button behaves the same way: it takes up all the horizontal space available, it's just that in this scenario, the horizontal space is not limited, while in the other project it was.